# mysql Query , calculate percentage of three grades

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate percentage of three different grades A,B,C

```
1 product have  A grade 
5 products have B grade 
3 products gave C grade
```

SQL - This Query return 3 rows

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE pid = '480' AND grade IN 
  ( SELECT DISTINCT grade FROM table1 ) 
  GROUP BY grade

  ------------------------
   CCA_ST2      count(*)
  ------------------------
     A            1 
     B            5
     C            3
 ------------------------
```

How can i calculate percentages ?

```
   (  SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE pid = '480' AND grade IN 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT grade FROM table1 ) 
      GROUP BY grade
   ) 
   DIVIDE BY 
   ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE pid = '480' ) * 100
```

I tried with this query

```
SELECT grade,
( SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE pid = '480' AND grade IN 
  ( SELECT DISTINCT grade FROM table1 ) 
  GROUP BY grade
) 
/ 
( SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE pid = '480' ) 
* 100 
AS score 
FROM table1 GROUP BY grade
```

I got this error . How can i solve this

```
subquery returns more than one row
```

i don't really want to create procedure for this , i know this can be done by query . But i'm feeling so lazy today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't take the count from all groups and divide them by the total count, you have to divide each count by the total count:

```
SELECT
  grade,
  100 * count(*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE pid = '480') AS score 
FROM table1
WHERE pid = '480'
GROUP BY grade
ORDER BY grade
```